# How does a roof top ventilator work?

Tags: everyday-life

[image]

I have spotted this on the rooftops of industries, workshops, etc. 
I guess this is used for providing ventilation. This is not electrically powered. But then how does this work??

Comment: That is a wind-driven ventilator.

Comment: @KyleKanos- A friend of mine argues that, its the exhaust of warm air from under the roof that makes the ventilator rotate and further assists in the process..I cant counter his point

Comment: I am pretty sure that it is the wind on the outside that is driving it.

Comment: I have recently seen lots of them on sale in an open-air store and with a light breeze they do spin fast.

Answer (score 1):

I am familiar with such equipment. There are several kinds and are wind-driven. There is a  paper [A review on wind driven ventilation techniques](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0378778808000443) about passive ventilation techniques.